# hash tables in python

Tags: python, hash

I started learning hash tables, so could anybody explain how the programm works. Although, where should I write a list with values?

The code is here:
http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/342511

Comment: Asking the very same question twenty minutes later again? Don't be rude and repost the same questions within twenty minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking at is an implementation of Hash Tables with chaining.

The purpose of this is to avoid hash collisions by creating a chain of values in which their hash values are the same.

The general implementation is that the key contains a pointer to a linked list. When you want to insert a value, you add your new element to the linked list where the hash value is the key of that linked list.

You can read more about this here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining

Comment: could you supply me with a code, so that I could understand that in a more clear way?

Comment: Here is a solution in java that is pretty straight forward: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/Hashtablewithseparatechaining.htm